# Set click as default

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013, filtering

I´m using   [Megafolio](http://hastypudding.org/assets/lib/megafolio/documentation/documentation.html)     so now I filter category with clic, but I want to set default category when page loads, how can I do that?

There is my filter function

```
function completeGalleryContent(data, target, eng) {
var items = data.d.results;
console.log(items);
var menu = "";
var cat = "";
for (var item in items) {
if(items[item].DescriptionEnglish==null)
    items[item].DescriptionEnglish="";
if(items[item].Description==null)
    items[item].Description="";
    if(items[item].Categoria.results!= null && items[item].Categoria.results!= undefined && items[item].Categoria.results.length > 0){
        cat =setCategories(eng,items[item].Categoria.results);
    }
    if (eng){
        
        menu += "<div class='mega-entry " + cat + " cat-all' id='mega-entry-1' data-src='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' data-width='' data-height='' data-lowsize=''><div class='mega-covercaption mega-square-bottom mega-landscape-right mega-portrait-bottom mega-red'><div class='mega-title'>" + items[item].TitleEnglish + "</div><p>" + items[item].DescriptionEnglish + "</p></div><div class='mega-coverbuttons'><div class='mega-link mega-red'></div><a class='fancybox' rel='group' href='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' title='" + items[item].TitleEnglish + "'><div class='mega-view mega-red'></div></a></div></div>";
    }else{
        menu += "<div class='mega-entry "+ cat + " cat-all' id='mega-entry-1' data-src='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' data-width='' data-height='' data-lowsize=''><div class='mega-covercaption mega-square-bottom mega-landscape-right mega-portrait-bottom mega-red'><div class='mega-title'>" + items[item].Title + "</div><p>" + items[item].Description + "</p></div><div class='mega-coverbuttons'><div class='mega-link mega-red'></div><a class='fancybox' rel='group' href='" + items[item].EncodedAbsUrl + "' title='"+ items[item].Title +"'><div class='mega-view mega-red'></div></a></div></div>";
    }
 }
 $(target).html(menu);
  var api = $(target).megafoliopro(
                {
                    filterChangeAnimation: "pagebottom",            // fade, rotate, scale, rotatescale, pagetop, pagebottom,pagemiddle
                    filterChangeSpeed: 400,                 // Speed of Transition
                    filterChangeRotate: 99,                 // If you ue scalerotate or rotate you can set the rotation (99 = random !!)
                    filterChangeScale: 0.6,                 // Scale Animation Endparameter
                    delay: 20,
                    defaultWidth: 980,
                    paddingHorizontal: 10,
                    paddingVertical: 10,
                    layoutarray: [9, 11, 5, 3, 7, 12, 4, 6, 13]     // Defines the Layout Types which can be used in the Gallery. 2-9 or "random". You can define more than one, like {5,2,6,4} where the first items will be orderd in layout 5, the next comming items in layout 2, the next comming items in layout 6 etc... You can use also simple {9} then all item ordered in Layout 9 type.
                });

        //console.log("entra");
        // FANCY BOX ( LIVE BOX) WITH MEDIA SUPPORT
        jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox();
        //console.log("sale");

        // THE FILTER FUNCTION
        $('.filter').click(function () {
            $('.filter').each(function () { jQuery(this).removeClass("selected") });
            api.megafilter(jQuery(this).data('category'));
            $(this).addClass("selected");
        });
 var categorySelected = getParameterByName("Category");

$("div[data-category='"+categorySelected +"']").click();

 }
```

I try change these line like these but did´t works:

```
var categorySelected = getParameterByName("Office");
```

Or something like

```
var categorySelected = getParameterByName().first;
```

To take first one populated of db

Comment: you can select attribute data-category using $('[data-category]') and can perform click event.

Comment: You mean something like `var categorySelected = $('[data-category]')`? @varit05

Comment: Yep and you can check specific value as well : $('[data-category="Office"]').click()  reference here : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: Excelent!, other question, if I have different languages on my app, how can I use "or" statement into jQuery, something like `$('[data-category="Office"]').click() || $('[data-category="Oficinas"]').click();` but didn´t work, only works if I dont use OR statement @varit05

Comment: jQuery selector is like css selector : `$('[data-category="Office"],[data-category="Oficina"]').click();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery, you can use [click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[href="#first_steps"]').click();
});
```

Just change first_steps by other link if you want.

**EDIT**

With data-category :

```
$('[data-category="Office"]').click(); // An html attribute with value
```

Comment: The problem is I don´t have href class, category html output is something like `<div class="filter" data-category="Office">Office</div>`

Comment: See my edit @Gerry. You can select everything in html with jQuery.

Comment: Excelent!, other question, if I have different languages on my app, how can I use "or" statement into jQuery, something like `$('[data-category="Office" ||"Oficina"]').click();`

Comment: @Gerry You can use regex or like css `$('[data-category="Office"],[data-category="Oficina"]').click();`